# Manifolds question

Tags: general-topology, analysis, functions, manifolds

Let $M$ subset of $R^{n+p}$ be the zero set of a $C^\infty$ mapping $g:R^{n+p} \rightarrow R^{p}$. Assume that the Jacobi matrix of $g$ has rank $p$ everywhere on $M$. Show that $M$ is an $n$-dimensional manifold.

Comment: hint: implicit function theorem